# Select all objects from model that respond true to the Model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say that I have a Model called Game.

That model have two fields, start_date (timestamp) and time_limit (integer)

I want to select all objects, that will return true to following statement:

```
start_date + time_limit.minutes > Time.now
```

I managed to get all objects where start_date is greater than time now, but that's not what I exactly wanted.

```
Game.where(["start_date > ?", Time.now])
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Couple of questions - what database adapter are you using? (MySQL, Postgres, etc.) and is `time_limit` always in minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PostgreSQL**

```
Game.where("start_date > now() - time_limit * interval '1 MINUTE'")
```

Answer (score -1):

As `start_date + time_limit.minutes > Time.now` this is a simple inequation you can also write the same as: `start_date > Time.now - time_limit.minutes`

So your query should be:

```
Game.where(["start_date > ?", Time.now - time_limit.minutes])
```

✌️